# Kotlin BufferedReader from stream is blocking

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating an android app with visual studio on clocking, and I'm trying to make the communication between my C++ server (working perfectly) and my android app.
My android socket (client) connect correctly to my serv, i can send message to the server, but when the server is sending message the readText block indefinitly.
here the code for the current fragment :

```
package com.example.androidapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.androidapp.databinding.FragmentServerMainBinding
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import java.io.Reader

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.*

class ServerMainFragment : Fragment() {
    //private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentServerMainBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentServerMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        singleton_ServerInfos.end=false
        binding.bBisconnect.setOnClickListener {
            singleton_ServerInfos.end=true;
            Log.d("ServerMainFragment", "closing socket")
            singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket?.close();
            (context as Activity).runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                Log.d("ServerMain: ", "disconnecting")
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.FirstFragment)
            })
        }

        binding.sendmsg.setOnClickListener {
            Thread(Runnable {
                try {
                    Log.d(
                        "ServerMainFragment",
                        "sendmsg" + singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.isConnected
                    )
                    singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket?.outputStream.write("Hello from the client!".toByteArray())
                } catch (excep: java.net.SocketException) {
                    Log.d("SocketException", "catched error")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("Exception", e.toString() + "---" + e.message)
                }
            }).start()
        }
        listenForServerMessage()
        Log.d("FirstFragment", "onViewCreated")
    }

    fun listenForServerMessage() {
        //var reader = Scanner(singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream())
        Log.d("ServerMain ", "listenForServerMessage")
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                Log.d("ServerMain ","letsgo:"+singleton_ServerInfos.end);

                var bufReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader (singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream()))
                while (singleton_ServerInfos.end!=true) {
                    Log.d("ServerMain ", "while")
                    var nbr = singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream().available()
                    if (nbr != 0) {
                        Log.d("ServerMain read: ", "in:"+nbr+"-"+bufReader.ready());
                        if (bufReader.ready())
                            Log.d("ServerMain read: ",  "NOOWOWW:"+bufReader.readText());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("ServerMain: ", "exception closing.")
            }
        }).start()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

The socket is connected on the previous fragment. In the reading function listenForServerMessage , i check if the socket is ready, i check the number of bytes received (non zero) and if the buffer is also ready, both are good but when executing readText i get an infinite loop.
my log look like this :

```
D/ServerMain: letsgo:false
D/ServerMain: while
I/chatty: uid=10122(com.example.androidapp) Thread-3 identical 73 lines
D/ServerMain: while
D/FirstFragment: onDestroyView
D/ServerMain: while
...same while log until i send a message from the server...
I/chatty: uid=10122(com.example.androidapp) Thread-3 identical 1686 lines
D/ServerMain: while
D/ServerMain read:: in:8-true
```

I tried many thing but can't figure a solution, and i know my socket correctly receive the message because if i close the C++ server, the android socket finaly read the message.
(i'm planning to send image buffer through the socket in the future)

Comment: Do you flush at the server side after writing?

Comment: no i dont, it's a c++ server so i don't have the "flush" functionnality, but it's working well with my C++ client, but i will check what does the flush function, maybe it's a character to send :)

Comment: Also, I think you shouldn't interact with `clientSocket.getInputStream()` directly if you already wrapped it in a buffered reader. What if buffered reader read the message already and stored it in its internal buffer? `available()` for the original stream will return `0` while we have data to read from the buffered reader.

Comment: I found the flush function, but there seem to be no character send :( [android flush](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream#flush())  [geek flush](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bufferedoutputstream-flush-method-in-java-with-examples/), i'm currently trying to send random non visible ascii character from my c++ server

Comment: I tried every character to add (from 0 to 255) at the end of my message, none worked

Comment: If your client in C++ worked correctly, then I assume this is unrelated to flushing. Did you try to not use any loops, `available()` and `ready()`, but simply invoke `readText()`? At least for testing. Do you do anything else with this thread while waiting for data? If not, then I think you don't need to check if you can read.

Comment: No i do not for now, yes i tried on using the readText but still the same error. I dont know what to try

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution, the only for me to have a non-blocking read is to use a **CharArray** in the read function, every other function end-up in a infinite loop (even **read()** without argument)
Here the code that work now:

```
fun listenForServerMessage() {
        //var reader = Scanner(singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream())
        Log.d("ServerMain ", "listenForServerMessage")
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                Log.d("ServerMain ","letsgo:"+singleton_ServerInfos.end);

                var bufReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader (singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream()))
                while (singleton_ServerInfos.end!=true) {
                    Log.d("ServerMain ", "while")
                    var nbr = singleton_ServerInfos.clientSocket.getInputStream().available()
                    if (nbr != 0) {
                        Log.d("ServerMain read: ", "in:"+nbr+"-"+bufReader.ready());
                        var mchar : CharArray = CharArray(nbr)
                        if (bufReader.ready()) {
                            bufReader.read(mchar)
                            Log.d("ServerMain read: ", "!!!:" +mchar.concatToString());
                        }
                        else
                            Log.d("ServerMain ", "fail")
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("ServerMain: ", "exception closing.")
            }
        }).start()
    }
```

I will now implement the logic of how i wanted to use my server, if i found a cause of this problem, i will edit my answer.